# Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large in R (RGui 64-bit)

Tags: r

I am doing work for Data Mining on R and i am facing this problem i dont know how to tackle this problem kindly help: here is my attempt:

```
 csv <- read.csv("F:/Semester 7/IDM/Project/d3.csv", header=TRUE)
> ct <- as.data.frame(csv)
> k<- kmeans(m,4,500)
> cluster <- k$clusters
> plot(csv,col=clusters)

Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large
```

any idea?

Comment: Do any of [these](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=Error+in+plot.new()+:+figure+margins+too+large+site:stackoverflow.com) help?

Comment: i reduce the iterattion e.g kmeans(m,2,100) but i dont know how to reduce margin as u have said and even i am nt familar with windows size...

Comment: alex thanks but i meeet these i dont know whats wrong happening . i also attepmted par(...) but did nt help.

Comment: Here's [another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20418264/kmeans-on-a-million-observations-in-r-trouble-plotting-clusters) (much more specific).

Comment: after cluster? ok i am trying kindly correct me if wrong?

Comment: by following alex i have found this one "Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
  object 'center.2' of mode 'function' was not found
"

Comment: Your plotting window is too small. Enlarge it and see your problem solved.

Comment: You'll need to adapt your code to his example (that error is probably because you forgot to copy the part where `center.2` is assigned a value). At least one of the two solutions given (re-sizing the plot window or plotting a random sample) should give you what you're looking for.

Comment: i am sorry man i failed to understand completely i could not able recognize. I tried very harder to resolve. if u can put solution for me so that i can understand the example....